# Commits Getting Stuck on Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Solr Version is 6.4.2 , java version 1.8.151 ,os Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, cloud Provider -GCP
I am using solrj to index data on solr .
For past two weeks when I index data the commits gets stuck (hours).
I add list of documents at a time.
Then I restart the solr and immediatly after

1. when I index a bulk of data again it gets stuck

2. if I index very small number of documents it starts commiting again.

I have reindexed the whole core to avoid the index corruption.
Tested it with different minor version of java but both did not work out

Comment: Have you tried changing to a [different lockType](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-lockType)?

Comment: No I have not tried those . I have three cores running in a single solr instance . ONly one core is being stuck . Number of records in core is 24 Million. My current Locktype is "native"

Comment: I assume the three cores are using different directories for their index files (i.e. they're not all using the same underlying directory and files). Initial guess is that native locking might cause issues when the disk resource is mounted to the VM through GCP under certain load conditions, and that the lock type might change that. I'd try using `simple` for that specific core and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks will try .

Comment: @MatsLindh it did not work . I think It should have something to do with Merge . but The system has been up for more than year on same setup and parameters . I Am not able to think what bug have I might have hit.

Comment: Do you have enough free space on the disk? Seems weird when you can reindex the whole core again, though .. and no of the other cores have any issues.

Comment: @MatsLindh yes I do have space     
/dev/sdb        148G   38G  103G  27% /abc/
I can share Thread Dump As well

Comment: @MatsLindh Thread Dump Link : https://gofile.io/?c=QcParF

Comment: @ MatsLindh  I think I found It . A field with 6mb of data was inserted in database . which was creating a stalling condition in IndexWriter . So applied a length check and it seems to work